# wxPython windows stuck in background

Tags: python, windows-7, wxpython

I have a wxPython project that is showing some weird symptoms in Windows 7 (everything works fine on Mac OS X, Windows 7 is the only win version we're testing against for this version). The app has a subclass of wx.TaskBarIcon with a right-click menu that should create windows that should always stay on top. Each window is a subclass of either wx.Frame or wx.Dialog created by wxFormBuilder.

Sometimes, and I cannot find the steps to reproduce it, the windows don't show up and cannot be called to the front. The app's icon will appear in the taskbar but the window will not appear. Clicking the icon does nothing and even by closing all other windows the window is not shown.

Snippet of how I'm currently showing the window:

```
#Initialization code, calling super's __init__ etc.
self.Center()
self.Show()
self.SetWindowStyle( self.GetWindowStyle() | wx.STAY_ON_TOP )
```

Since I can't reproduce the problem debugging it is hard. I've tried calling self.Raise and self.SetFocus after self.Show but the problem comes up again now and then. Has anyone experienced similar problems with wxPython or know any possible fixes for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I recall, you normally can't change Frame styles after initialization reliably. You should just put the STAY_ON_TOP style flag in the Frame's init instead. For dialogs, use ShowModal(). Now that I think about it, you can also use the frame's MakeModal() method and that would probably work too.

Comment: Thanks. Using ShowModal was not really an option as the dialogs can't be blocking. But I think (as I said, can't really test it when I don't know what causes it) your comment about changing styles after initialization got this working for me :)